# PHP Manage Sessions per User

Tags: php, authentication, session

On my Website any connecting Client will get a Session assigned. Upon user verification/login/oauth That session will get `$_SESSION['LoggedIn']` set to true and some user data from database put in $_SESSION like username, upon log out or expiration that session will get cleared and destroyed.
However if a User is on a different device he will get a complete new session. He of course also has to log in there to also link that new Session to his Account.
On Twitter and Google for example it is possible to list all those Session on all those devices, and even terminate those. So how could  I link those Sessions from the same User in PHP? especially since everything i put into $_SESSION would be only in that session. In that regard it might be wise to put user data from the database in Redis instead of $_SESSION. Or is there generally something wrong with my approach ?

Comment: Put all the session IDs in a database table.

Comment: oh yeah xD and if the session gets destroyed i need to remove that database entry. is there a way to trigger that when after some time that session is closed by php?

Comment: Not without a custom session handler I think. You could run a periodic cron job that removes rows that don't have a matching file in the session directory.